# Calculating grades through midterm and final

Tags: vb.net

For my class in Visual Basic I need to calculate a semester grade based on the score of a midterm and a final test. My problem is that the final must count for twice the amount as the midterm, I keep on getting numbers over 100. Here is what I have so far,

```vb
    Private Sub btnDet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDet.Click
        Dim mid As Double = CDbl(txtMid.Text)
        Dim final As Double = CDbl(txtMid.Text)
        Dim grade As Double = (mid + final + final) / 2
        Math.Ceiling(grade)
        lblGrade.Text = CStr(grade)
    End Sub
```

......

Comment: You should change the tag to VB.Net, which is different than VBA. However, the error is simply that you should divide by 3, not by 2 :)

Comment: I'm going to upvote this answer because, when mids are 75% and the final is 55% students will get 0.616 with his suggestion, and 0.605 with mine. Here's the code if you fancy http://goo.gl/2uNPxd. Not to mention it requires fewer changes.

Comment: @Clovola you seem so generous with your students :). In fact you graded on 99, not on 100. you can reach the same result by adding some more decimals (0.33333, 0.66666) ;)

Comment: Sorcery. Witchcraft. Maths.

Comment: @clovola lol, I dont think a student will fail for that. That is why your answer is totally valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just consider the midterm 1/3 the grade, and the Final 2/3 the grade? So in code you'd just multiply `mid * 0.33` and `final * 0.66` and those added together would give you your grade.

Here's was my thought process:

`Private Sub btnDet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDet.Click
    Dim mid As Double = CDbl(txtMid.Text) * 0.33
    Dim final As Double = CDbl(txtMid.Text) * 0.66
    Dim grade As Double = mid + final
    Math.Ceiling(grade)
    lblGrade.Text = CStr(grade)
End Sub`